# Why doesn't echo $rslt variable

Tags: php, cookies

I have the following code, and I cant find why doesn't echo $rslt[0]["product_id"]; ?
The cookie is in the browser, can anybody tell me what is wrong?

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["jshopping_temp_cart"])) {
    mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("shopping_katalog") or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM x9qg6_jshopping_cart_temp WHERE id_cookie ='".$_COOKIE["jshopping_temp_cart"]."'");    
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $data = $row['cart'];
        $rslt = unserialize($data);
        echo $rslt[0]["product_id"];
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see any `echo` or `print` in given example. I assume it's a typo. To be sure what's inside `$rslt` use `var_dump($rslt);`.

Comment: Also, remove real username and password from code and stop using `mysql_*` since it's deprecated. You can use `mysqli_*` and/or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 7):

You're not using `echo`, so it won't echo.

Answer (score 4):

You need to `echo` it ;)

```
 echo $rslt[0]["product_id"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually calling echo here at all, also if you call echo on a variable that doesn't have a value then it will not echo a value at all.

`echo $rslt[0]["product_id"];`

to ensure there's something actually in the variable:

`var_dump($rslt[0]["product_id"]);`

Answer (score 0):

echo is missing in your code. please modify your code like:

```
  if (isset($_COOKIE["jshopping_temp_cart"])) {

    mysql_connect("localhost", "shopping_katalog", "logik@112233") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("shopping_katalog") or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM x9qg6_jshopping_cart_temp WHERE id_cookie ='" . $_COOKIE["jshopping_temp_cart"] . "'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $data = $row['cart'];
        $rslt = unserialize($data);
        echo $rslt[0]["product_id"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can echo the required field or use print_r() to display all result like print_r();